# HTML generated string not showing as HTML

Tags: c#, html, css

HTML generated string is not showing as HTML on GUI, but as plain string. I've put non-breakable spaces and `<br/>` inside this string, but it doesn't show up as HTML.

Column with this problem is `[Naziv izdelka]`. What am I doing wrong? Why is HTML not showing as HTML but as plain string?

[Here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/MpxQzy?editors=1000) is example.

Here is code where I generate this table (column cPROD_NME):

```
iQuery qPackage = db.LoadInsertSMPRPR_BASE(null, iPROD_KEY, null, "1", null, null, null, null, null, "5");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int counter = 1;
if(qPackage.RecordCount() > 0)
{
  while(!qPackage.EOF() && counter <= 5)
  {
    double? decPRPR_QUA = qPackage.AsFloatN("PRPR_QUA");
    string cPROD_NME1 = qPackage.AsStringN("PROD_NME1");
    string basicUnit = qPackage.AsStringN("basicUnit");
    sb.AppendLine($@"-&nbsp;&nbsp{decPRPR_QUA}x {cPROD_NME1} [{basicUnit}]<br/>");
    counter++;
    qPackage.Next();
  }
}
cPROD_NME += "<br/>" + sb.ToString();
```

Comment: The values have been decoded you need to encode them. Is this WebForms or MVC?

Comment: It's MVC, using visual studio.

Comment: What do you do with `sb`? are the values correct in the `StringBuilder` if you breakpoint and check?

Comment: Yes they are correct. Everything looks good, I guess it must be encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your question how the contents of your `StringBuilder` gets rendered on your view. Look at the helper function `Html.Raw()` which allows you to write to the view with no decoding. And check out `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

`Encode()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx

`Decode()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

`Raw()`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx